# C# convert List into Branch

Tags: c#, list, recursion, tree, branch

I have a list of strings in C#:

```
List<string> { "A", "B", "C", "D" };
```

These strings are 'titles' of product categories.

I need to convert them into a branch of nodes like this:

```
A > B > C > D
```

The order of the items in the list determines their position in the branch, ie. A is the root and D is the leaf node.

My object is called `WebBrowseNode` and it has properties:

- `string Title` (`string`)
- `List<WebBrowseNode> Children`

I have been at this for at least one hour now and can't find a proper algorhithm to do this.

Comment: One clue: start with the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to start with the end of your list.

```
WebBrowseNode lastNode = null;
for (int numItem = list.Count - 1; numItem >= 0; numItem--)  // Go from the end to the beginning of the list
{
    string title = myStringList[numItem];

    lastNode = new WebBrowseNode
    {
        Title = title,
        Children = { lastNode }                              // Adds lastNode to the Children list
    };
}

WebBrowseNode root = lastNode;
```

Comment: Thank you for this and for the quick reply. Let me try it.